# Avoiding hidden characters on the shell

Tags: shell, encoding, utf-8, keyboard, locale

If I type:

```
# ls ß[backspace]-l
```

(Or some other special character like "ü" instead of ß)
I get:

```
ls: cannot access �-l: No such file or directory
```

Another example:

```
# ß[backspace]ls
-bash: $'\303ls': command not found
```

This happens on CentOS 7 and BASH (v4.2.46).

```
# localectl 
 System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
     VC Keymap: de
    X11 Layout: de

# locale
 LANG=en_US.UTF-8
 LC_CTYPE="C"
 LC_ALL=C

# locale charmap
 ANSI_X3.4-1968
```

That last `ANSI_X3.4-1968` should probably be `UTF-8` (as defined by $LANG). But I don't know how to change it.

On Ubuntu and debian, (with equivalent settings, except the `ANSI`) the special characters get printed, but they can be deleted with one backspace (each).

How could I ignore non UTF-8 characters on the shell, or enable removing them with a single backspace?